# Linear Gradient overlay not Working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am putting a background Image and overlaying a gradient to make it darker of the overlay text is clearly visible. In IE its not working so I am using the `filter:` but that makes the gradient opaque. and the background is not visible... how to fix it?

```css
.more {display:block;width:33.33%; padding:15px;padding-top:6em;background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(http://placeimg.com/760/460/tech ) no-repeat; background-size: cover; border:2px solid white; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); text-decoration:none; color:white; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );     background-color: #eee;font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif; width:350px;font-weight:bold; font-size:1.45em}
```

```html
<a class="pod more" href="/markup-html-tags-and-formatting/">Markup: HTML Tags and Formatting</a>
```

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @vsync - Chose transparent colors `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000',GradientType=0 ); ` still background not visible in IE

Comment: have you verified this in another IE? maybe another version? This is only for IE9 and below if I remember correctly. what IE version have you tested this on?

Comment: @vsync I am using IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work...

```
/* approximately a 33% opacity on blue */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
  startColorstr=#550000FF, endColorstr=#550000FF
);

/* IE8 uses -ms-filter for whatever reason... */
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
  startColorstr=#550000FF, endColorstr=#550000FF
);
```

**Link** : http://jsfiddle.net/ps7h7bf3/

Answer (score 0):

user the following style will hopefully do the job for you

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#eeeeee', EndColorStr='#000000');

check the the Following link for quick understanding http://www.css3please.com/